# How to remove all non-alphanumeric and non-space characters from a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to remove all non-alphanumeric and space characters from a string. So I do want spaces to remain. What do I put for a space in the below function within the [ ] brackets:

```
ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $title);
```

In other words, what symbol represents space, I know \n represents a new line, is there any such symbol for a single space.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just put a plain space into your character class:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9 ]
```

For other whitespace characters (tabulator, line breaks, etc.) use `\s` instead.

You should also be aware that the [PHP’s POSIX ERE regular expression functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php) are deprecated and will be removed in PHP 6 in favor of the [PCRE regular expression functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php). So I recommend you to use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) instead:

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $title)
```

Comment: I'm commenting simply to say Props for posting a proper example. The above green checked answer is technically incorrect. It should be: $title = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $title) instead of just: preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $title) clarifying that the method doesn't replace that variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only a literal space, put one in. the group for 'whitespace characters' like tab and newlines is \s

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does not remove spaces.

Consider the following

```
$string = 'tD  13827$2099';
$string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $string);

echo $string;

> tD  138272099
```

Now if we str_replace spaces, we get the desired output

```
$string = 'tD  13827$2099';
$string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $string);

// remove the spaces
$string = str_replace(" ", "", $string);

echo $string;

> tD138272099
```

Comment: This is true. I must be missing something since there's an accepted answer. I'm using `preg_replace('/[\s\W]+/'` and it works like a charm - strips out non-alphanumeric and spaces.

Comment: I know this is old, but the author doesn't want to remove spaces. 

"How to remove all non-alphanumeric and non-space characters from a string in PHP?" 

"What do I put for a space in the below function within the [ ] brackets:" 

and most notably: "So I do want spaces to remain". 

There's just a missing "non" in the first line of the text.